# can Autofac do different instance scoping per interface?

Tags: c#, autofac, lifetime-scoping

Suppose I have this line in my bootstrap code:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyType>().As<IMyType>().As<IMyTypeBase>().ExternallyOwned();
```

I want it such that whenever I use `container.Resolve<IMyType>()` I get a new instance of `MyType`. However, if I use `container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IMyTypeBase>>()`, I don't want new instances. I want all of the instances that have already been created. Is this possible with Autofac?

Comment: I agree with @Steven. What's the purpose of such need?

Comment: I have some items that need to be disposed last. My plan was to mark them as ExternallyOwned and then acquire them when I am ready to destroy the autofac container.

Comment: Then, may be .OnRelease() method could help you, or you can use OnActivated() to track all IMytypes that were resolved. Or you can always write your own IRegistrationSource which won't be very difficult.

Comment: Does OnRelease() trigger on items marked with ExternallyOwned()?

Comment: Yes. It does trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement seems conflicting and you should reconsider your strategy. The behavior you want can lead to very surprising results and determines on the order in which types are resolved or even in which order the constructor parameters are ordered.

Take a look at the following example for instance:

```
var instance1 = container.Resolve<IMyType>();
var instance2 = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IMyTypeBase>>().First();

Assert.AreSame(instance1, instance2);
```

Here we first resolve the `IMyType` and later resolve the collection of `IMyTypeBase` instances and you expect the collection to return the same instance. But what if we turn this around?

```
var instance2 = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IMyTypeBase>>().First();
var instance1 = container.Resolve<IMyType>();
```

Do you still expect both instances to be the same? When `Resolve<IEnumerable<IMyTypeBase>>()` is called, there is no `MyType` instance yet, so it will be created. But your requirement is to always create a new instance when resolving `IMyType`, so in this case two instances will be created.

To make this worse, take a look at the following two constructors:

```
public SomeService(IMyType type, IEnumerable<IMyTypeBase> types) { ... }

public OtherService(IEnumerable<IMyTypeBase> types, IMyType type) { ... }
```

The simple fact that `OtherService` defines the `IEnumerable<IMyTypeBase>` parameter first, will cause two `MyType` instances to be created. And you might be able to see this in this particular case, but since object graphs can become very deep, it becomes almost impossible to guess the number of instances of `MyType` to be created.